# T-SQL The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have this query I'm creating, but I'm stuck with this error:

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "UPDATE Tech_Helpline.dbo.Calls
SET Tech_Helpline.d..." failed with the following error: "The multi-part identifier "LampsGarLive.dbo.i8pupu_Tech Hotline Primary Members.AssociationName" could not be bound.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

These two tables are from separate databases (within the same SQL Server). What I'm attempting to do is merge the AssociationNames from the i8pupu table (AssociationName Column) to the Calls Table (Association Column) where (Calls.NRDS = [i8pupu_Tech Hotline Primary Members].NRDSMember_id). I need to retain all rows from the Calls table.

Note: I am placing this code in a SQL Server 2008R2 SSIS package using the Execute SQL Task tool.

```
UPDATE Tech_Helpline.dbo.Calls
SET Tech_Helpline.dbo.Calls.Association = LampsGarLive.dbo.[i8pupu_Tech Hotline Primary Members].AssociationName
FROM Tech_Helpline.dbo.Calls As T1
LEFT JOIN LampsGarLive.dbo.[i8pupu_Tech Hotline Primary Members] AS T2
ON T1.NRDS = T2.NRDSMember_id
```

Anyone want to help me with this? Thanks for the help!

Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the alias:

```
UPDATE T1 
SET T1.Association = T2.AssociationName
FROM Tech_Helpline.dbo.Calls As T1
      LEFT JOIN LampsGarLive.dbo.[i8pupu_Tech Hotline Primary Members] AS T2
ON T1.NRDS = T2.NRDSMember_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made the changes. The code is cleaner, but I receive this error now: [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "UPDATE T1.Calls
SET T1.Association = T2.Associatio..." failed with the following error: "Invalid object name 'T1.Calls'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: I am doing this in a SQL Server 2008R2 SSIS package using the Execute SQL Task tool. Will this make a difference?

Comment: I think you have taken the query before my edit. It should be `UPDATE T1 ..` **NOT** `UPDATE T1.Calls ..`